# Which class would inherit a Controller in a project ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I am following a tutorial to build Web API Application, but I do not understand from which class a controller has to inherit.

In my tutorial is explained to inherit from ControllerBase, but around the web I saw that Controller who inherit from ApiController.

What is the best path to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`"I am following a tutorial to build Web API Application, but I do not understand from which class a controller has to inherit?"`***

> First of All you didn't shared which document you are following, on
> the other than it depends which kind of `asp.net` or `asp.net core` project
> `controller` you have taken. For example if you have taken `asp.net core controller` it should be inherited from `ControllerBase`
> if you have taken `asp.net MVC` it should be inherited from
> `Controller` but if you have taken only `asp.net web API controller` it should be inherited from `ApiController` as you may know [`Web API controllers inherited from ApiController`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/controller-differences)

So here is the details what you are confused on:

***`Asp.net Web API2 Controller Inherited From ApiController:`***

> It has been developed on asp.net framework 4.8 before .Net core.

[image]

***`Asp.net Core MVC Controller Inherited From Controller:`***

> Developed on `asp.net core MVC`

[image]

***`Asp.net Core Controller Inherited From ControllerBase:`***

> All `asp.net core` no matter `MVC` or `Web API` Inherited  from
> ControllerBase. After release version of asp.net core 2.1, you
> wouldn't get anything Inherited `ApiController` all from
> `ControllerBase` and curently on `.Net 5.0` or `.Net 6.0`

[image]

***`"In my tutorial is explained to inherit from ControllerBase, but around the web I saw that Controller who inherit from ApiController?"`***

It depends on which version of `asp.net` or`asp.net core` project you are working on. If you are using `asp.net core 5.0` or latter than it should use `ControllerBase` by default as convension.

> **Note:** If you would like to know more details on diffrent kind of `ASP.NET MVC and Web API with controllers or even ASP.NET Core` [`you can check here our official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/controller-differences)

Hope it would guided you accordingly.

Comment: Okey, I am using ASP.NET Core Controller and following your great answer, I can understand I have to use ControllerBase. Really useful, thank you ver much Farid!

Comment: Glad to assist you.